# php html form select option to populate text field jquery

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

I'm editing a wordpress plugin:

It currently has a dropdown option list for a user, and based on that user, I want to fill a text field with that users email.

selection option dropdown:

```
<div>
    <label for="Customer_ID"></label>
    <select name="Customer_ID" id="Customer_ID" />
    <option value='0'>None</option>
    <?php foreach ($Customers as $Customer) { ?>
      <option value='<?php echo $Customer->Customer_ID; ?>'><?php echo $Customer->Customer_Name; ?></option>
    <?php } ?>
    </select>
</div>
```

The customer email is stored in $Customer->Customer_Email

And Im trying to fill in the following value when a user changes the selected user:

```
<div class="form-field">
  <label for="Order_Email"></label>
  <input type='text' name="Order_Email" id="Order_Email" />
</div>
```

I've played around with filling the Order_Email with the following script, but it just sents the value as the customer_id.  How do I change the value to the email

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#Customer_ID').on('change', function () {
        var selection = $(this).val();
        $('#Order_Email').val(selection);
    });
});
</script>
```

Comment: dirtiest way is just to pre load the email values into a data attribute then just put that as value into the text field, of course it'll reveal every email on that option tag ala inspect element, might as well just use an xmlhttp request, fetch the email according to selected option, get the response and put the email into the textfield

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could just add a title attribute to the options to equal whatever the email value is:

Play around with it here: http://jsfiddle.net/7BUmG/3876/

This might not be the best solution and hacky, but it should do the trick.  This will also break after the plugin is updated

```
<div>
    <label for="Customer_ID"></label>
    <select name="Customer_ID" id="Customer_ID" />
    <option value='0'>None</option>
    <?php foreach ($Customers as $Customer) { ?>
      <option title='<?php echo $Customer->Customer_Email; ?>'value='<?php echo $Customer->Customer_ID; ?>'><?php echo $Customer->Customer_Name; ?></option>
    <?php } ?>
    </select>
</div>
```

and

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#Customer_ID').change(function() {
    var email = $(this).find("option:selected").attr("title");
    $('#Order_Email').val(email);
});
});
```